# AWS Glue - Create date partition from timestamp field

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, etl, aws-glue

Having a data frame with a timestamp field, like so:

| timestamp | id | version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 01:02:00.000 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-01-01 05:12:00.000 | 1 | 2 |

I've created a Glue job that is using `ApplyMapping` to save the data to a new S3 location. Currently I've added **id** and **version** partition by selecting those fields in the visual editor and my data is saved with the following structure: `id=1/version=2/` I would like to parse the timestamp and extract the date value so the filesystem structure would be `id=1/version=2/dt=2022-01-01/`. However, in the visual editor I can only select the timestamp and cant perform any manipulation on the field. I'm guessing I need to change the code, but I'm not sure how.

Code:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node S3 bucket
S3bucket_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="parquet",
    connection_options={"paths": ["s3://my-data"], "recurse": True},
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node1",
)

# Script generated for node ApplyMapping
ApplyMapping_node2 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=S3bucket_node1,
    mappings=[
        ("timestamp", "timestamp", "timestamp", "timestamp"),
        ("id", "string", "id", "string"),
        ("version", "string", "version", "string"),
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node2",
)

# Script generated for node S3 bucket
S3bucket_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=ApplyMapping_node2,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="glueparquet",
    connection_options={
        "path": "s3://target-data",
        "partitionKeys": ["id", "version"],
    },
    format_options={"compression": "gzip"},
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node3",
)

job.commit()
```

Comment: Why do you want to save the fields in this structure? You are partitioning using columns with a very high cardinality

Comment: I'm using TTL so data is deleted after 30 days, I want to be able to go to a specific date in the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Map Class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-map.html).

Add this method to your script

```py
def AddDate(rec):
    ts = str(rec["timestamp"])
    rec["dt"] = ts[:10]
    return rec
```

Insert the Map Transform after the `ApplyMapping` step.

```py
Mapped_dyF = Map.apply(frame = ApplyMapping_node2, f = AddDate)
```

Update the write to S3 step, notice the change to `frame` and `partitionKeys`.

```py
S3bucket_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=Mapped_dyF,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="glueparquet",
    connection_options={
        "path": "s3://target-data",
        "partitionKeys": ["id", "version", "dt"],
    },
    format_options={"compression": "gzip"},
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node3",
)
```